# How to import the given file properly?

Tags: import, string-manipulation, data

Consider the [following file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xnafvo86v8sjmvc/Efficiencies.dat?dl=0). It has the structure of a table, with rows like

```
LHC HNL dipole  0.5 0.00001 e   {"HNL dipole", 0.5, 0.00001, 0.}
```

Here, the columns are LHC, HNL dipole, 0.5, 0.00001, e, {...}.

I fail to import it. Namely, if importing in the following way,

```
data = Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
    "Efficiencies.dat"}], "Table"];
```

I get

```
data[[1]]
```

> {"LHC", "HNL", "dipole", 0.5, 0.00001, "e", "{"HNL dipole",","0.5,", "0.00001,", "0.}"}

I.e., "HNL dipole" is separated as "HNL" and "dipole", while the data in the sub-row is completely unreadable:

```
data[[1]][[7]]
```

> "{"HNL dipole","

Could you please tell me how to import the file properly?

Comment: `d2 = Import["C:/Efficiencies.dat", "TSV"]`. Now if this works, then please  say how you would like to manipulate this data further. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ReadList["~/Downloads/Efficiencies.dat", "Word",
  RecordLists -> True, WordSeparators -> {",", "\t", " ", "{", "}"}]

(*    {{"LHC", "HNL", "dipole", "0.5", "0.00001", "e", "HNL", "dipole", "0.5", "0.00001", "0."},
       {"LHC", "HNL", "dipole", "0.5", "0.00001", "Î¼", "HNL", "dipole", "0.5", "0.00001", "0."},
       ...
       {"FCC-hh", "HNL", "dipole", "7.", "19.952623149688787", "Î¼", "HNL", "dipole", "7.", "19.952623149688787", "0.000024379781172545756"}}    *)
```

If you don't like the `"Î¼"` parsing, you can do `% /. "Î¼" -> "\[Mu]"`. Also, `ToExpression` converts the strings to numbers, if desired.

Answer (score 6):

Each line of the file contains 6 tab separated fields, so `Import` should specify the TSV format.  The last field can be trimmed to remove the braces and then parsed using `ImportString`.  For example

```
data = With[{raw = Import["Efficiencies.dat", "TSV"]},
         raw /. {x___, y_String} :> {x, Flatten@
           ImportString[StringTrim[y, {"{", "}"}], "CSV"]}
   ];

data//First//Last   (* {"HNL dipole", 0.5, 0.00001, 0.}}  *)
```